# Image loading with GCD receiving memory warning

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, alassetslibrary, nsautoreleasepool

I'm developing a photo gallery application using AssetsLibrary to load my device photos. When presenting a random image in another VC I've noticed the following : it takes about 1 or 2 seconds for my full res image to load on the imageView (way much longer than the native photosApp) and I also get from the log "Received memory warning" after loading a few images. If I set my representation to fullScreenImage the warnings stop but I don't want this. What must I change for a smooth performance and high quality images on the view ?

Here's the code,hope you can tell me what's the problem :

This is the VC where I want to present my image on the screen

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@",assetsController);

    detailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:detailImageView];
    detailImageView.image = smallImage; //small image is my asset thumbnail and is passed as an argument in my init function

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        ALAsset *asset = [assetsController.albumPics objectAtIndex:assetsController.index];
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

        bigImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]]retain];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            detailImageView.image = bigImage;

        });
        [pool release];
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
    {
        UIImageView *detailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        [self.view addSubview:detailImageView];
        detailImageView.image = smallImage;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            ALAsset *asset = [assetsController.albumPics objectAtIndex:assetsController.index];
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

            UIImage *bigImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                detailImageView.image = bigImage;

            });
            [pool release];

        });
}
```

[image]

Comment: try releasing [bigImage release]; after detailImageView.image = bigImage;

Comment: @bhuXan tried this already and still getting warnings after a few image loads...

Comment: using jpeg images or converting png to jpeg should do....

Comment: It's just a hunch but what do you get if you `NSLog` an asset? Does it look like a Core Data object?

Comment: @Tommy the output when I log is : **Photo_Share[1420:907] See Asset: ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000072&ext=JPG**

Comment: @Tommy the previous log was from within the block where I obtain my assets; this one is from the `main_queue()`: **Photo_Share[3020:907] ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=36D993A0-E188-42CE-869C-91E56076E99D&ext=JPG This is the asset**

Comment: That doesn't look like a Core Data object to me; have you tried using Instruments to see what sort of objects are remaining alive? Other than that I'm pretty sure `UIImage +imageWithCGImage:` is thread safe now but you could try grabbing the `CGImageRef` outside the block and then creating the `UIImage` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Is `bigImage` an instance variable? Is it used in any place other than here? If it is not used anywhere else, then it should be a local variable, and you shouldn't retain it. If it is an instance variable that you retain, you need to release the previous value before assigning a new value to it.

Same discussion applies to `detailImageView`

Comment: Indeed, both were instance variables but never used somewhere else so I've transformed them into local variables.Take a look at the update

Comment: also, `detailImageView` needs to be released at the end of the method

Comment: just released it, same results ; now I will ask: doesn't **detailImageView** gets drawn every time the view has loaded if I make it local ?